# Add +1 for data attributes not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This's my codes:

```
var following_tags = $('.follow-tags-start').attr("data-following-tags");

$('.follow-tags-start').attr('data-following-tags', following_tags+1);
```

the issue that if the count of `data-following-tags="0"` after do the action the count add 1 with the exists count so each time i do the action it's add 1 with 0.
`data-following-tags="01111"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `parseInt()` (assuming these are integer numbers) to convert data attribute to integer, then you can add 1. something like this:

```
var following_tags = parseInt($('.follow-tags-start').attr("data-following-tags"));

$('.follow-tags-start').attr('data-following-tags', following_tags+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a callback, and coerce the value to a number

```
$('.follow-tags-start').attr("data-following-tags", function(attr) {
    return (+attr) + 1
});
```